# JTextField window does not appear

Tags: java, graphics, jtextfield

On a panel, I'm adding a textfield and a button.
I'm trying to change size or position of the textfield but it doesn't change.
See example [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjACd.png)

```
/**
 *
 * @author Tsiatas
 */
import javax.swing.*;


public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JButton button;

    public MyFrame() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        textField = new JTextField();
        panel.add(textField);
        button = new JButton("press me");

        panel.add(button);
        this.setContentPane(panel);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(800, 400);
        this.setTitle("My first test frame");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you try o change size and position? Btw from the docs `Each JPanel object is initialized to use a FlowLayout`

Comment: Please work on the formatting. The comment should also go into the code section. You should also clearly state your question

Comment: by typing textField.setSize(400,500);

Answer (score 0):

You are missing explicit setting of preferred size of the textfield.
The below code will work in a way:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

   private JPanel panel;
   private JTextField textField;
   private JButton button;

   public MyFrame() {
       panel = new JPanel();
       textField = new JTextField();
       textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20)); // This is the added line
       panel.add(textField);
       button = new JButton("press me");

       panel.add(button);
       this.setContentPane(panel);
       this.setVisible(true);
       this.setSize(800, 400);
       this.setTitle("My first test frame");
       this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   }
}
```

For changes in positioning you will need to use a layout on the `JPanel`. Each layout has its own special configuration.